# Telerik Rad Grid Button caption

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, telerik-grid

Hi I'm looking but can't see

Is there a way to change the caption on a gridButton on a Telerik RADGrid (on a ASP.NET web page) , depending on another of the bound fields (in this case active) e.g if active = true text = "Disable", if active = false then text "Enable"

I have resolved the issue by iterating through the e.items on the databound event, but wonder if there a 'cleaner' method for doing this

Cheers

Comment: What set of thir components are you using? WInforms? ASP.Net? Silverlight? WPF?

Comment: Updated the question ... but its' a Telerik radgrid, running on ASP.NET web page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnItemDataBound would be the right place.